# Draw rectangle into the Array

Tags: equations, arrays, shapes

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
16\cdot I_1  & + & 11\cdot I_2  & =& 13\\
11\cdot I_1 & + & 16\cdot I_2 & =& 17
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is to draw a rectangular shape to unknown variables and known coefficients. This equation may be 3 or 4 variables. An example figure is below. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there is a nice `tikz` way to do this, but here, I just lay out a succession of columns, with `\fbox`es around the appropriate ones.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,xcolor}
\TABstackMath
\newcommand\redbox[1]{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\fboxsep=2pt
\fboxrule=1pt
\tabbedCenterstack{16\cdot\\11\cdot}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{I_1\\I_1}}
\tabbedCenterstack{+11\cdot\\+16\cdot}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{I_2\\I_2}}
\tabbedCenterstack{=\\=}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{13\\17}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even though I don't use tabbed columns, I use `\tabbedCenterstack` in lieu of `\Centerstack`, so that I can employ the `\TABbinary` feature, which adds `{}` to each side of every column, which will assure proper spacing for `=`, `+`, and `\cdot`.

Comment: Your answer worked, but another problem occurred in my document. Would you like to answer my question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493680/33075

Comment: @Özgür Let me have a look

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `hf-tikz` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[norndcorners,customcolors,nofill]{hf-tikz}

\hfsetbordercolor{red!70}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tikzset{left offset=-0.02,right offset=0.02,disable rounded corners=true}
\begin{array}{@{} *{2}{ c @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} } c @{}}
16\cdot \tikzmarkin{A}I_1  & + & 11\cdot \tikzmarkin{B}I_2  & = & \tikzmarkin{C}13\\[1ex]
11\cdot I_1\tikzmarkend{A} & + & 16\cdot I_2\tikzmarkend{B} & = & 17\tikzmarkend{C}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer worked. But when I had my entire document in mind, Steven B. Segletes responded to my request.