# Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored in tabstackengine

Tags: horizontal-alignment, stackengine, phantom

My MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
  \nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\TABstackMath
\newcommand\redbox[1]{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\shortminus}{\mathbin}{AMSa}{"39}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\TABbinary
\fboxsep=2pt
\fboxrule=1pt
\tabbedCenterstack{\\\shortminus}
\tabbedCenterstack{41\\55}
\tabbedCenterstack{~\cdot~\\~\cdot~}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{U_1\\U_1}}
\tabbedCenterstack{~-~\\~+~}
\tabbedCenterstack{\phantom{1}14\\1\pmzerodot3} % <- Problem line
\tabbedCenterstack{~\cdot~\\~\cdot~}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{U_2\\U_2}}
\tabbedCenterstack{~=~\\~=~}
\redbox{\tabbedCenterstack{273\\561}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Original image

[image]

I want to add a dot to the number 0. So I added `\pmzerodot`.

[image]

I want to justify to the right number 14. So I added `\phantom{1}`.

[image]

Finally `\phantom{1}` and/or `\pmzerodot` gives an error. Can this problem be solved?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry for writing fast. I tried to detail the my question now.

Comment: I get no error from the posted code

Comment: This was the worst for me. Now, I need to check the packets, updates ...

Comment: I suspect your version is out of date.  It works for me.  For reference, `tabstackengine 2018/03/05 (V2.10)` which loads `stackengine 2017/02/13 v4.01`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, only `\pmzerodot` added **Illegal parameter number in definition** error writing. I uploaded it, March 5, 2018 V2.10 `tabstackengine.sty`. It gave the following error. **File listofitems.sty not found**. I have included the following files. `listofitems.sty`, `listofitems.tex`, `listofitemsold.tex`. It writes the following error. And instead of `\pmzerodot` 0 when I add the number writes. **l.67 {\input listofitemsold.tex \relax\endinput**

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, by adding only `\phantom {1}` **Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line XXX** error writing. I have included the following files. `listofitems.sty`, `listofitems.tex`, `listofitemsold.tex` It writes the following error. And when deleted `phantom {1}`. **l.67 {\input listofitemsold.tex \relax\endinput}**. I deleted all the files I added.

Comment: @Özgür A major change was made to V1.62 of `listofitems`...it now relies on TeX-engine support for the `\expanded` primitive, a new feature that has been added to e-TeX engines.  If you are still relying on an engine that does not support `\expanded`, it instead loads your prior version of `listofitems`.  I have to consider what would happen if you did not have any prior version of `listofitems` AND if your current TeX engine does not support `\expanded`.

Comment: I have manually checked out what happens if `listofitems` V1.62 is installed, but on an older TeX engine.  In this case, `listofitems` detects the inability to use V1.62 and instead loads V1.61 (given at ctan.org as `listofitemsold.tex`.  So, all I can say is that your problem should and does compile when `listofitems` is installed, old or new version.